# Connect Sequelize to Oracle DB with a Cloud Wallet

Tags: node.js, oracle, sequelize.js

I need to connect my Node.js + Sequelize application to a secured database with a Cloud Wallet
Currently I have a .zip file that contains :

- cwallet.sso
- cwallet.sso.lck
- ewallet.p12
- ewallet.p12.lck
- sqlnet.ora
- tnsnames.ora
- company-certificate.crt

I tried to connect from SQLDevelopper client with the zip file and it worked but now I need to connect from NodeJS + Sequelize

This is what I tried to do

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const _sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database.servicename, config.database.username, config.database.password, {
    host: config.database.address,
    port: config.database.port,
    dialect: config.database.dialect,
    logging: false,
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl: {
            ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../../company-certificate.crt')
        }
    }
});

_sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('Connection to DB : [OK]');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Connection to DB : [KO]');
});

module.exports = _sequelize;
```

this is the error returned by the connector :
"original: Error: NJS-500: connection to the Oracle Database was broken"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oracle dialect for sequelize doesn't support `ssl` as `dialectOptions`.
You can use `connectString` option inside `dialectOptions`.
Set the `$TNS_ADMIN` environment variable to your wallet location.

```
const _sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: config.database.dialect,
  username: config.database.username,
  password: config.database.password,
  dialectOptions: {
    connectString: <alias_from_tnsnames.ora>
  }
});
```

check [tnsnames.ora security section](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/netrf/local-naming-parameters-in-tns-ora-file.html#GUID-7DF419C2-3237-4B79-9AA3-EA1C2D786712) to configure your alias according to your need.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to also include SSL even if it's not in dialectOptions ?

Comment: For 1-way TLS , you can set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=<wallet_location>/company-certificate.pem  if the certs are not in std CA certs path.  after converting .crt format to .pem format by using openssl:
`openssl x509 -in mycert.crt -out mycert.pem -outform PEM`

Comment: For mtls, walletPassword and walletLocation have to be specified inside `dialectOptions`. The walletLocation should have single `ewallet.pem` which can include client certificates (ewallet.p12 has to be converted to pem appended with CA cert in pem using above openssl cmd ). See [mtls node-oracledb](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#mutual-tls-connections-to-oracle-cloud-autonomous-database)

Comment: NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS should have single pem bundle containing all the CA certs along with the Oracle server/client  CA certs. On the same lines,  walletLocation passed in dialectOptions shall have a single pem file, ewallet.pem with combined client certificate(ewallet.p12 converted to pem)  and CA certificate chain associated.  I hope this clarifies?